# What does this mean: "Why would that be the case?"

Tags: meaning, american-english

What does a person mean when they ask this question: ***"Why would that be the case?"***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"to be the case" is an idiom meaning "to be thus" or "to be true"

"Why would that be the case?" -->  "Why would that be true?" --> "What leads you to believe that that is true?"

Answer (score 0):

It is a statement about what would be the case.

*If you wanted to ask your question and not tell others that you were wondering about it, this would be the proper order, and it would take a question mark.* In such a situation we use these types of sentences

Answer (score 0):

In a question with would the speaker expresses his astonishment and at the same time that he doesn't find the matter normal.

Comment: That's one possible context. My immediate thought was that it was a teacher trying to elicit an explanation from a student of something the student had written: no astonishment there.